# A robust, full-feature UIWebView controller implementation?

Tags: iphone, browser, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to put as feature-complete of an embedded browser as possible into my iPhone app. It's just going to be pushed onto a UINavigationController when a user taps a URL from a user's profile view.

It should:

- Have the full set of expected browser controls and loading status indicators using standard icons: back, forward, loading spinner, stop button, open in safari button, etc.
- Properly handle networking and other loading failures with alert popups (cancel/retry etc)
- Deal as intelligently as it can with mailto:// and possibly other non-http links
- Ideally, have an editable location bar
- Respond to all interface orientations
- Generally be as a good as a browser can be in-app, without sending the user to the Safari app.

A UIWebView by itself needs a lot of help to get all these trimmings in place, and all the online tutorials I've found via Google are cursory. Plus there are variety of gotchas (like the mailto:// link issue which I found out about the hard way, etc.)

I'm hoping to not have to reinvent the wheel here to get as complete a browser as possible. Is there an open source implementation somewhere that I've failed to find?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, it should handle YouTube and other media links properly. What you get if you just rely on the default behaviour is... strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there an open source implementation somewhere that I've failed to find?" Not that I know of. 
to handle mailto:// tel:// all you need to do is UIWebView delegate there is a method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSURL *clickedURL = [request URL];
    NSString *clickedURLString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",clickedURL];
    NSString* checkURLValid = [clickedURL host];
    NSString* schemeOfURLClicked = [clickedURL scheme];
}
```

you can get scheme of the clicked URL .. if its mailto:// then do something, tel:// [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1-800-275-2273"]];

But still safari vs UIWebView is lots different. UIWebView cannot handle pop-ups directly. You might want to look into that http://niw.at/articles/2009/02/06/how-to-enable-the-popup-window-on-uiwebview/en and handling authentication is not built into UIWebView this is a hack http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/33944-http-basic-authentication-request-uiwebview.html Rest of the UIWebView you can find a tutorial anywhere.